# Help with Application Settings

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, application-settings

I'm developing the settings page for an iPhone application I'm working on. The basics are simple enough but there are some interesting things I've seen in the settings for some of the default iPhone and I was wondering if they are easy to create.

Two things in particular are having a UITextView as a child pane (an example of this is the signature in the Mail app settings) as well as having settings appear and disappear based on a switch (an example would be in the Wifi settings).

Any ideas if these are somewhat easily achievable?

EDIT: I'm aware I can achieve a similar effect by creating a custom settings page. What I want to know is if the things I mentioned are possible for application creators.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UITableView` and build your custom subclasses of `UITableViewCell` class for various settings. You can easily manipulate a table view for making things appear and disappear dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As @Kakosquid suggested you can try a table view with custom cells. You can go through this [tutorial](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/) for more info on custom cells